# Convert sql Non-Unicode parameter to Unicode

Tags: sql, unicode, sql-like, nvarchar

I have two records in my person table in my database, their last names are "تحصیلداری" and "موقر".
when I use

```
select * from Person where Lastname like N'%ی%'
```

the record containing "ی" character in last name returns, which is exactly what I need, but I need a little change. I need to use the word between `%` and `%` as a parameter.
Something like :

```
create procedure usp_GetPersonsWhoseNameContains(@LN nvarchar(50))
as
begin
    select * from Person where Lastname like N'%'+@LN+'%'
end

declare @LastName nvarchar(50) = 'ی'
exec usp_GetPersonsWhoseNameContains(@LastName)
```

but it does not work this way, and in my searches I couldn't find the appropriate solution. Does anyone know how to

Comment: What error you are getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
create procedure usp_GetPersonsWhoseNameContains(@LN nvarchar(50))
as
begin
    select * from Person where Lastname like N'%'+@LN+'%'
end

declare @LastName nvarchar(50) = N'ی'
exec usp_GetPersonsWhoseNameContains(@LastName)
```

Maybe you noticed that SQL Server uses N to any quoted string input when generating DDL scripts for you.

Comment: my problem is that I want to use this stored procedure in a C# application and fill the parameter from there, and AFAIK I cannot put an N behind it from C# App, so how should I do it?

Comment: how you passing it currently , can you give code for that? Try to put N in code side also before parameter as i put here in sql.

Comment: static public List<Person> GetPersonContaining(string word)  
{  
    PersonTableAdapter.GetPersonsWhoseNameContains(word);  
}

Comment: I have a DataSet, containing a TableAdapter for Person table, and have added a Query (using an existing stored procedure)

Comment: i am not getting you exactly but some where you using something like                                                       SqlCommand cmd  = new SqlCommand("CustOrderHist", conn);

            // 2. set the command object so it knows to execute a stored procedure
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            // 3. add parameter to command, which will be passed to the stored procedure
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CustomerID", custId)); Here instead of @CustomerID try to give N@CustomerID.